# Excel 2007 - Compare 2 columns, find matching values

Tags: excel-2007

I have two colums. Column A and Column B which have email addresses. Column A has about 3000 rows, Column B has about 1800.  Is there anyway to compare the two columns, and find any fields that match...

And if so, how to either highlight or flag them as a match... or shit, for even simplicitys sake, just give me a count of how many matches were found...

Should i try a macro?  Or is there a forumula that will help with this?

Answer (score 8):

You could fill the C Column with variations on the following formula:

=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,$B:$B,0)),"",A1)

Then C would only contain values that were in A and C.

Answer (score 0):

`=VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)` will solve this issue.

This will search for a value in the first column to the left and return the value in the same row from a specific column.

Answer (score 0):

VLOOKUP deosnt work for String literals